# I am getting stuck in a for loop for no reason using timer

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread running that keeps updating my laskAck variable. I am setting my time-out to be extremely large on purpose so that my thread have a chance to update laskAck variable. When I debug my code and run step by step it works but if I run it normally, program pauses at if (timePassed > timeOut). Any idea why this happens???

```
long timeout = 40000000;
while (lastAck != sent) {
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            packetSentTime = send_timer[(sent - 1) % cwnd];
            timePassed = currentTime - packetSentTime;
            if (timePassed > timeOut) {
                ssthresh = (int) (Math.ceil(cwnd / 2));
                cwnd = 1;
                sent = lastAck;
                System.out.println("Time out occured\n" + lastAck);
                timeout = true;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you investigated the `volatile` keyword? You might look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369742/why-doesnt-this-java-loop-in-a-thread-work?rq=1)

Comment: Thankyouu!!! Been stuck on this for an hour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a variable that is being updated by another thread, the variable must be declared in a way that supports thread safety. One approach is to use the `volatile` keyword. Other approaches would possibly include using types from the `java.util.concurrent` packages.

In the particular case here, ensure that the variable `lastAck` is declared as:

`volatile long lastAck;`

and the loop check will always pull the value from memory rather than caching it.

Answer (score 0):

Java is case sensitive, so `timeout` is not the same as `timeOut`. You need to change the condition to `timePassed > timeout`.

Comment: That's a typo when I was copying the code. I just needed to add volatile keyword as @KevinO suggested